# NextJS - can't acces cookies in getServerSideProps

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering, httpcookie

I need to access cookies at getServerSideProps function to verify user but i can't acces any cookie

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = nookies.get(context); // get undefined
  const { req, res } = context;
  const token = context.req.headers.cookie; // get undefined
  // req.cookies is also undefined
    console.log(token);
   
            return {
                props: {
                    cookies:cookies,
                }
            };
}

export default MainPage;
```

I can see cookie in the browser and it's not making a difference if its a httpOnly,secure or whatever.
Here is part of the code where i set the cookie but i don't think it's a problem

```
res.setHeader("Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("userToken", token, { maxAge: 43200,}));
res.status(200).send(payload);
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay i figured it out, in case someone else is struggling with this i just had to set cookie path on creation to "/", like this:

```
 res.setHeader("Set-Cookie",
                cookie.serialize("userToken", token, {
                  maxAge: 43200,
                  path: "/", 
                  httpOnly: true,
                  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
                })
              );
```

Comment: big thanks, can't believe that actually worked lol

Comment: Thank you! I struggled way too long, but this solved it for me!